# Scheduled event chat-room link in the inbox takes you to the transcript instead of the room

Tags: feature-request, chat

Scheduled event chat-room link in the inbox takes you to the transcript instead of the room.

Sufficient to say, the fix should be to take you to the room, not the transcript, if we're *before* the event. If we're *after* the event, the current behavior is fine.

Answer (score 3):

No, it shouldn't. I hate links that take you directly to the room, because now you've involuntarily joined the room, so now you're subscribed to that room's events. Even ignoring the events pain, you shouldn't be forced to join a room just because you clicked a link; chat shouldn't even allow that, there should be a prompt of some kind before you accidentally join the I <3 Racism room because you clicked a random link in a comment

Comment: There is a difference between an inbox notification for a chat event you have subscribed to and a random link elsewhere...